# The tire has less air(don't have enough air)

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

If a tire doesn't have enough air, is it common to use "less air"? Like my mom is driving,so she says:

> I guess the tires have **less** air.

Is the use of "less" natural?

Comment: I can't imagine ever talking about the air in that context: I would talk about the **pressure**.

Answer (score 2):

Saying the tires have "less air" needs some comparison:

> The tires have less air than they should have.
>
> The tires have less air than recommended.

Alternatively, it is quite usual to say

> The tires are **underinflated**.

As given in the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underinflated) dictionary.

> **underinflated**
>   *not sufficiently inflated*

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not your intended meaning.

It is correct and natural however, but that statement would mean that tires have less air than something else, and given that you said driving I would assume you are comparing them to the tires on another car you have driven recently.

Comment: So won't it mean "I guess the tires don't have enough air"?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish No. It just means they have less. I would probably assume they still have enough unless you specifically said "The tires don't have enough air."